# Firebase DB how does the offline cache works on android?

Tags: android, firebase

I am wondering if I cache all the data from firebase and after turn off the wifi it will work as well as was before. But if I turn off the wifi and restart the phone and enter the program without wifi, will it work?

Comment: Firebase has 18 products. Which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can still query the data, as it's been persisted on the device's storage.  This should be pretty easy for you to try for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you use room or localstorage to save data, it is functioned

Example

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
with (sharedPref.edit()) {
    putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore)
    commit()
}
```

Link del code

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Room

dependencies {

```
  def room_version = "2.2.5"

  implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
  annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

  // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
  implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

  // optional - RxJava support for Room
  implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

  // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
  implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

  // Test helpers
  testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
}
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhM-Qi8en6gIVCZ2zCh3PMQSNEAAYASAAEgIUP_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

You only need to save the json